# Best practice for hosting a large image library

Tags: codeigniter, cdn

I'm looking into setting up a fairly large scale image library site. I'm looking at CodeIgniter for the framework as I hear it's easy to work with and quick. What I'm looking for help on is the server set up. I've been speaking to a company about getting hosting set up as its's not something I've had much experience with.

I know a Content Delivey Network is worth thinking about, as is using something like Varnish, but don't want to start building anything only to have to redo it to take this into account.

So my question is this: What's the best way to go about setting this up? Start building the site as efficiently as possible and worry about speeding the server up later or is it something that needs sorting up before anything's built.

Comment: You need to define parameters in order to have a 'best way' method. Its all in the numbers, how many users, how many images, what is the goal, etc. Are you building the next flickr?

Comment: I thought that might be the case. I'm purely thinking technical requirements at this point. So just as general as possible is it best to code then try and speed up on the server or get the server architecture right first and then code? I appreciate it might be a bit 'vague' though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend building a working site to meet your most basic requirements. Don't worry about features or requirements that are so far off they may never materialize. You can always refactor and improve performance, but requirements and priorities often change, especially once you have something to work with and people are actually using your site.

Having to constantly change/improve working code is often better than doing lots of planning up front, only to end up realizing later that you made a wrong assumption and have to make major changes on a code base that never worked. This is basically Agile vs Waterfall.

If you like PHP, CodeIgniter is a quick way to get started. The most important thing is to be sure to **follow conventions** and be **consistent** so that you can easily make major changes without worrying about breaking everything, or having to maintain lots of documentation.

I wouldn't worry about Varnish yet. CodeIgniter has lots of caching options built-in. You won't have millions of users over night, so if you find your growth trajectory going vertical, you can always re-align your priorities at that point. Also, explosive growth is usually tied with people giving you lots of money, so you have more options on solving that "problem".

I would start out with a CDN, as it seems like an essential part of your site. It will largely address image backup as well. Just be sure to comparison shop, because CDN services vary quite a bit. Also, for simplicity, you may want to look into origin-pull.

Comment: Not sure. Seems like a perfectly valid answer.